# What is the number of paritions of an array without changing the relative order of the elements of the array?

Tags: math, combinations, combinatorics

We are given an array of n integers (not necessarily distinct). What is the total number of ways to partition the array into contiguous non-empty subarray?

Example: Array A = [1,2,3]. Then the number of partitions will be 4:

```
{1,2,3}

{1} {2,3}

{1,2} {3}

{1} {2} {3}
```

Wrong partition : {1,3} {2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will first explain for the given array A = [1,2,3] and then extend it to array of length N.

Let us represent the elements of the array as 3 **distinct** kingdoms. It doesn't matter if the elements of the array are distinct or not, we *have to assume they are distinct*. Also, assume there is Binary Switch between any 2 adjacent kingdoms. If the switch is **1**, then a **partition** is created between the two adjacent kingdoms **else no partition**.

```
1 [0] 2 [0] 3 --> {1,2,3}

1 [1] 2 [0] 3 --> {1} {2,3}

1 [0] 2 [1] 3 --> {1,2} {3}

1 [1] 2 [1] 3 --> {1} {2} {3}
```

So we see that each switch has 2 possibilities [0] and [1]. Different combinations of these switches lead to different partitions. Hence the total number of partitions is 2 x 2 = 4.

Extending for N elements, there will be (N - 1) switches and each switch has 2 possibilities and the total number of partitions will be 2 x 2 x 2 x ... x 2 (N - 1) times = 2^(N - 1).